# Iterative type conversion over list of iterables

Tags: python, iterator, list-comprehension, python-itertools

I have got such a list of strings:

```
names = ['Katia', 'Alexandre']
```

and I want to achieve this result:

```
['Katia', 'Alexandre', 'Katia Alexandre', 'Alexandre Katia']
```

*i.e.* I need all the permutations of size *range(1, length(names)+1)*.

I wrote this function that produces a list of iterables:

```
import itertools

def permutations_all_sizes(iterable):
    sizes = range(1, len(iterable)+1)
    permutations = [itertools.permutations(iterable, x) for x in sizes]

    return permutations
```

Now, my idea was to execute a nested list comprehension to untuple the strings. However, wheter I do it nested or not nested the result is always the same:

```
perms = permutations_all_sizes(names)

[list(tup) for tup in perms]
[162]: [[('Catia',), ('Alexandre',)], [('Catia', 'Alexandre'), ('Alexandre', 'Catia')]]

[list(tup) for tup in [iterator for iterator in perms]]
[165]: [[('Catia',), ('Alexandre',)], [('Catia', 'Alexandre'), ('Alexandre', 'Catia')]]
```

Can somebody explain why such behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired output with the following list comprehension:

```
print([' '.join(names) for tup in perms for names in tup])
```

---

Explanation of behavior of your code:

`names = ['Katia', 'Alexandre']`, so

`sizes = range(1, len(iterable)+1) = range(1, 3)`, so

`permutations = [itertools.permutations(iterable, x) for x in sizes] =`

`= [itertools.permutations(iterable, 1), itertools.permutations(iterable, 2)`.

`itertools.permutations(iterable, 1)` contains tuples of length 1 of elements of iterable:

```
names = ['Katia', 'Alexandre']
for something in itertools.permutations(names, 1):
    print(something)  # will print ('Katia',) then ('Alexandre',)
```

so doing `list(tup)` of this permutation object will give a list of tuples like `[('Catia',), ('Alexandre',)]`.

Same logic applies to `itertools.permutations(iterable, 2)`:

```
names = ['Katia', 'Alexandre']
for something in itertools.permutations(names, 2):
    print(something)  # will print ('Katia', 'Alexandre'), then ('Alexandre', 'Katia')
```

and `list(tup)` will give `[('Katia', 'Alexandre'), ('Alexandre', 'Katia')]`

Combining them in a list comprehension `[list(tup) for tup in perms]` will give the output you get: `[[('Catia',), ('Alexandre',)], [('Catia', 'Alexandre'), ('Alexandre', 'Catia')]]`

Modifying list comprehension to `[list(tup) for tup in [iterator for iterator in perms]]` does nothing: `perms` is already a list and `[iterator for iterator in perms]` is equivalent to `perms`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `' '.join` method to join a tuple of strings into a space-delimited string:

```
def permutations_all_sizes(iterable):
    sizes = range(1, len(iterable)+1)
    permutations = [' '.join(permutation) for x in sizes for permutation in itertools.permutations(iterable, x)]
    return permutations
```